# Bean Shell Scripting issue with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How can I get the Response Time difference of http requests (E.g. Request1 -- Response time , Response 2 --Response time) and write to CSV file? I tried,  but was getting invoking eval shell error

```
long request2 = prev.getTime(); 
// get HTTP Sampler 2 execution time 
long request1 = Long.parseLong(vars.get("LaunchPage")); 
// get HTTP Sampler 1 execution time from variable 
long delta = (request1 - request2); 
// calculate difference 
log.info("Time difference is: " + difference + " ms"); 
// print difference to jmeter.log file 
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("E:/Kohls/TestData.csv",true //
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("e://delta.csv", true); 
    out.write((String.valueOf(delta)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
log.info("Time difference is: " + difference + " ms");
```

by

```
log.info("Time difference is: " + delta + " ms");
```

Also you can use Filewriter in Jmeter to write the output to a csv file.

Please check the following image for reference:

[image]